# Sorting in bash based on the number of occurrence of a specific character

Tags: text-processing

I need to sort a text file based on the number of characters in a line, then sort it based on the least number of blank characters i.e. spaces, if the number of characters in two lines are the same. I got the first part, but can't figure out how to do the second part. Can anyone throw me a bone?

Comment: Please some sample data would help and what you have done so far!

Comment: I posted it below, since i'm new to the site i don't know how to append a picture of my output in the text box.

Comment: Cross-posted using a different account? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364327/sorting-stdin-by-length-and-number-of-nonblanks-in-a-bash-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with `awk` and something like this:

```
awk -F " " '{print length($0), NF-1, $0}' file.txt
```

If you have multiple spaces use this one:

```
 awk '{NS=gsub(" "," ",$0); print length($0), NS, $0}' file.txt
```

- `gsub` replaces each space with a space and returns the count of this process, which is the number of spaces.

Let's say we got a file with this content:

```
here is something
here is something el s
here is something else
and agai n
and a a aa
```

the outpout of above command is:

```
17 2 here is something
22 4 here is something el s
22 3 here is something else
10 2 and agai n
10 3 and a a aa
```

First column is the number of characters, the second is number of spaces.

Then we pipe it to `sort` and `sort` will do the job, and after all I can use cut to only get the original file content:

```
awk -F " " '{print length($0), NF-1, $0}' file.txt | sort -k1n,2 | cut -f3- -d' '
```

For the second solution:

```
awk '{NS=gsub(" "," ",$0); print length($0), NS, $0}' file.txt | \
sort -k1n,2 | cut -f3- -d' '
```

And the final output is:

```
and agai n
and a a aa
here is something
here is something else
here is something el s
```

You can change `-F " "` with your specific character say "R":

```
awk -F "R" ...
```

or

```
gsub("R","R",$0)
```

for the second one.

Comment: I think that you want to change your sort to `sort -k1n,2n` to force a numerical, rather that alphabetical sort (so 203, comes after rather than before, 23)

Comment: I tried your code, but it's not preserving multiple spaces between words or letters. I tried using IFS='%', but then it won't sort based on the number of least amount of white spaces first if both lines have the same number of characters. Here is my code

Comment: here is my code .      #!/bin/bash                                                                                  

text=()
IFS='%'
echo "Please type a sentence, then press enter to type another sentence.                     
When you're done, hit ^D."

while IFS= read -r line
  do
  echo $line >> tmp
done

awk -F" " '{print length($0), NF-1, $0}' tmp | sort -k1,1n -k2n | cut -f3- -d' '

rm tmp

Comment: here is the output      Yangs-MacBook-Pro:Documents school$ bash prog2
Please type a sentence, then press enter to type another sentence.
When you're done, hit ^D.
this is a test
this      test
a a
aaa
 a
a
aD
 a
aaa
a a
this      test
this is a test
Yangs-MacBook-Pro:Documents school$

Comment: apparently i don't know how to use this site's features, how do i take a screen shot and append it to the text box?

Comment: I Updated my answer ;)

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! I've been trying all day trying to figure out why awk keeps truncating leading spaces, then when i figured out how to preserve them awk wouldn't count any of the leading spaces.

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept the question if it worked for you ;)

Comment: What is accepting the question? This is my first time using this sight. Btw what is the reason why we have to replace a space with a space? Is the first set of spaces a special character in disguise?

Comment: There is a gray tick bellow the number three, you can check that to accept the answer. we just using replacement to count the spaces, the first solution just won't works on multiple spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little Python script that does the job. Note that it removes all trailing whitespace characters from the every line before sorting and in the output.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Error, you must specfy the input file name as only argument!")
    exit(1)
lines=[line.rstrip() for line in open(sys.argv[1])]
print(*sorted(sorted(lines, key=lambda b:b.count(" ")), key=lambda a:len(a)), 
      sep="\n")
```

If you want to shorten it, leave lines 3-5 out, which only verify that exactly one command-line argument has been given and print an error message if this is not the case.

And here is a test run:
(with the script saved as `sort.py` and made executable using `chmod +x sort.py`)

```
$ cat loremipsum.txt 
Nostrum laboriosam et amet illum consectetur.
Voluptas quos doloribus totam porro inventore.
Molestiae ipsam quis dolores vero a delectus.
Aut cupiditate ullam possimus voluptate et delectus tenetur sint.
Omnis et vitae et blanditiis in et.
Inventore eligendi distinctio perferendis ab.

$ ./sort.py loremipsum.txt 
Omnis et vitae et blanditiis in et.
Inventore eligendi distinctio perferendis ab.
Nostrum laboriosam et amet illum consectetur.
Molestiae ipsam quis dolores vero a delectus.
Voluptas quos doloribus totam porro inventore.
Aut cupiditate ullam possimus voluptate et delectus tenetur sint.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Advanced Sorting](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/lperl/ch15_04.htm) from [O'Reilly's Learning `perl`](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/lperl/index.htm), you could do something like

```
perl -lne '
  push @arr, $_ }{ 
  for $x (sort { length($a) <=> length($b) or $a =~ tr/ // <=> $b =~ tr/ // } @arr) {
      print $x
    }
' file
```

Borrowing [@ByteCommander's input sample](https://askubuntu.com/a/913217/178692),

```
$ perl -lne '
>   push @arr, $_ }{ 
>   for $x (sort { length($a) <=> length($b) or $a =~ tr/ // <=> $b =~ tr/ // } @arr) {
>       print $x
>     }
> ' loremipsum.txt
Omnis et vitae et blanditiis in et.
Inventore eligendi distinctio perferendis ab.
Nostrum laboriosam et amet illum consectetur.
Molestiae ipsam quis dolores vero a delectus.
Voluptas quos doloribus totam porro inventore.
Aut cupiditate ullam possimus voluptate et delectus tenetur sint.
```

---

If you have GNU awk 4.0 or later, you can do a similar thing - although the custom sort function takes a bit more work e.g.

```
$ cat 2sort.awk 
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

function mycmp(ia, a, ib, b) {
  n = length(a) - length(b);
  return n == 0 ? gsub(/ /,"",a) - gsub(/ /,"",b) : n 
}

{arr[NR] = $0}

END {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "mycmp";
  for(i in arr) print arr[i];
}
```

giving

```
$ ./2sort.awk loremipsum.txt 
Omnis et vitae et blanditiis in et.
Inventore eligendi distinctio perferendis ab.
Nostrum laboriosam et amet illum consectetur.
Molestiae ipsam quis dolores vero a delectus.
Voluptas quos doloribus totam porro inventore.
Aut cupiditate ullam possimus voluptate et delectus tenetur sint.
```

Comment: thanks for the sample but i'm a linux noob, and i don't know pearl.