# How to filter data from txt using grep or sed?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am trying fetch data from twitter, I am able to read each line but do not know what commands to use to filter data like how I want. Any suggestions.

Input file : file.txt

```
id,created_at,text
842433,2017-05-20 14:45:05,goldring.com was just registered https://t.co/xt9345d
336353,2017-05-20 14:45:04,stretch.com was just registered https://t.co/QBEX965hf
84244e,2017-05-20 14:45:03,"Auctions were started for wantit1.com, wantit2.com, wantit3.com and wantit4.com"
842434,2017-05-20 14:45:02,"Auctions were started for sidefun.com, coffeetec.com, lifeout.com and new-fun-boys.com"
```

Expecting output:

```
wantit1
wantit2
wantit3
wantit4
sidefun
coffeetec
lifeout
new-fun-boys
```

Code I have :

```
cat file.txt | while read line; 
do

echo "$line"  >> out1.txt

done
```

Comment: What's the pattern here and what are you trying to achieve? Do you want the prefix of every word ending in `.com` from the third comma-separated column?

Comment: Yes I am looking for a pattern  Where I will get .com domains name list in the line having text 'Auctions were started for'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific input this will work:

```
grep -Po '\s[a-z1-9-]{2,}(?=\..{2,4})' file.txt
```

- `-P` : make us able to use look ahead.
- `-o` : only show the matchs.
- `\s` : only search for the ones which start with an space
- `[a-z1-9-]{2,}` Followed by any alpha-numeric character or hyphen, at least 2 or more.
- `(?=\..{3})` : which will be ended by a dot and 2 to 4 character (domain suffix) but do not include it.

Here is the output:

```
wantit1  
wantit2  
wantit3  
wantit4  
sidefun  
coffeetec  
lifeout  
new-fun-boys
```

A better idea (based on your comment) is to use:

```
awk '(/2017-05-20/ && /Auctions were started/)' file.txt | grep -Po '\s[a-z1-9-]{1,}(?=\..{2,4})'
```

Comment: This worked as what I want but I still have another question. I Want to get data with date '2017-05-20 only and output should be in sorted by length of domain name.

Comment: @KasaramBala I updated my answer for first part of your question, for the second I've got an other answer: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913199/sorting-in-bash-based-on-the-number-of-occurrence-of-a-specific-character/913204#913204).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a couple of options.

KISS approach using two greps:

```
$ grep 'Auctions were started for' file | grep -o '\S*\.com'
wantit1.com
wantit2.com
wantit3.com
wantit4.com
sidefun.com
coffeetec.com
lifeout.com
new-fun-boys.com
```

More elegant:

```
$ perl -lne 'if (/"Auctions were started for (.*)"/) {print for split(/, | and /, $1)}' file
wantit1.com
wantit2.com
wantit3.com
wantit4.com
sidefun.com
coffeetec.com
lifeout.com
new-fun-boys.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this with a combination of `grep` to find all lines in `file.txt` containing the text "Auctions were started for", and `sed` to extract only the domain names without TLD and print one per line:

```
grep -Po '(?<="Auctions were started for ).*(?=")' file.txt | sed -r 's/and |,|.com//g;y/ /\n/'
```

---

Here's a breakdown of the command:

```
grep -Po '(?<="Auctions were started for ).*(?=")' file.txt
```

This scans `file.txt` line by line and matches anything (`.*`) that is preceded by the string `"Auctions were started for` and followed by another `"`. We need `grep`'s `-P` option to enable PCRE regular expressions (otherwise we could not use the `(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` regex lookarounds) and its `-o` option to only print the matched part of a line (excluding the lookarounds) instead of the whole line.

In a second step, we pipe the output of this first command into this `sed` command:

```
sed -r 's/and |,|.com//g;y/ /\n/'
```

This `sed` line actually contains two commands, `s/and |,|.com//g` and `y/ /\n/`.

First, `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` searches for the regular expression (extended regex actually, because of the `-r` option) pattern `and |,|.com`, which means `and` , `,` or `.com`. Then it replaces that with nothing, so these patterns actually get removed from the input line. The `g` in the end enables global search and replacement instead of just processing the first match on every line.

Second, `y/CHARACTERS/REPLACEMENTS/` translates all characters in the first field to their corresponding characters in the second field. Here I am using this to simply convert all remaining spaces to line breaks.